# Visual Studio 2015 Git Team Explorer has no "Related Work Items" section in the Changes pane

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

[This page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/02/linking-work-items-to-git-branches-commits-and-pull-requests/) describes linking a work item to a commit in VS. I just updated my VS to make sure I have the latest stuff, it's VS2015 update 3, but I don't have a Related Work Items section in my Changes pane. We are using VSTS and I can work with Git just fine, and I can even link items to commits using the `#` syntax and that works, but seeing a list would be more useful.

I cloned the repository manually, and it shows up in "Local Git Repositories" in the Connect pane, which makes me think something isn't "hooked up" to VSTS within VS2015. Is there a way to facilitate that connection, or do I just need to re-clone it not through the CLI?

Answer (score 41):

This is because Team Explorer isn't connected to the project. You don't need to re-clone it, connecting to the project from Team Explorer via following steps should fix it:

1. Click "Manage Connections" link.
   [image]
2. Select the project of your Git repository and then click "Connect" in the pop up dialog.

Now when you go to "Changes", you should see the "Related Work Items" section:
[image]

Comment: Just an FYI for others who are running into this. You won't be able to connect while you still have changes to commit. That's what happened to me. I couldn't figure out how to connect for the longest time because it wasn't possible due to my uncommitted changes. I finally gave up and committed first, and then it worked. So you need to make sure you commit first, then you can try to connect.